# Hard question simplify as much as possible following

Tags: fractions

$$\frac{x^3-49x}{ x^4-13x^3+50x^2-56x}$$

I get answer $\frac {x+3} {x-1}$ but my friend say it's wrong I dont understand please help me please

greetings from russia

Comment: This is not a differential equation!

Comment: How did you get the answer?

Comment: What are exactly the paranthesis and the division bar ? See this in both case : 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3-49x+%2F+(x%5E4-13x%5E3%2B50x%5E2-56x)
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%5E3-49x)+%2F+(x%5E4-13x%5E3%2B50x%5E2-56x)

Comment: Hint: try substituting $x = 10$. Your answer gives $13/9$, whereas the original expression equals $17/48$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{x^3-49x} { (x^4-13x^3+50x^2-56x)}=\frac{x(x^2-49)}{x(x^3-13x^2+50x-56)}=\frac{x(x-7)(x+7)}{x(x-2)(x-4)(x-7)}$$

Comment: i dont think answer so complicated im just 19 years old he would never give me such question to me